# Проблема при переносе блока калькуляции в метод нового класса

Tags: objective-c

Это из книги Аарона Хиллегаса "Программирование на Objective-C". Упражнение к Главе 19.

> Используя класс StockHolding из предыдущего упражнения, напишите программу, которая создает экземпляр класса Portfolio (портфель акций) И заполняет его объектами StockHolding из упражнения предыдущей главы. Объект Portfolio должен уметь вычислять свою текущую стоимость.

Если я просто помещаю этот блок в конец man, то получаю нужную сумму пакетов акций (33772.80):

```
CGFloat sum = 0;
for (StockHolding *n in portfolio) {
    sum += n.valueInDollars;
}
NSLog(@"%.2f", sum);
```

Но при переносе данной калькуляции в метод класса Portfolio - при вызове данного метода в main у меня появляется ошибка.

[image: Imgur]

[Ссылка на проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7g4xt4sxbv8f46/Stocks%20Portfolio.zip)

Код:

```
*Portfolio.h*

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "StockHolding.h"

    @interface Portfolio : NSMutableArray

    - (CGFloat)totalPortfolio;

    @end

*Portfolio.m*

    #import "Portfolio.h"
    #import "StockHolding.h"

    @implementation Portfolio

    - (CGFloat)totalPortfolio
    {
        CGFloat sum = 0;
        for (StockHolding *n in self) {
            sum += n.valueInDollars;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    @end

*main.m*

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "StockHolding.h"
    #import "Portfolio.h"

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {


            StockHolding *DHL = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
            [DHL setNameOfShare:@"DHL"];
            [DHL setPurchaseSharePrice:345.67];
            [DHL setNumberOfShares:23];
            [DHL setCurrentSharePrice:389.23];

            StockHolding *Sony = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
            [Sony setNameOfShare:@"Sony"];
            [Sony setPurchaseSharePrice:587.12];
            [Sony setNumberOfShares:14];
            [Sony setCurrentSharePrice:603.81];

            StockHolding *EPAM = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
            [EPAM setNameOfShare:@"EPAM"];
            [EPAM setPurchaseSharePrice:178.45];
            [EPAM setNumberOfShares:35];
            [EPAM setCurrentSharePrice:190.64];

            StockHolding *BELAZ =[[StockHolding alloc] init];
            [BELAZ setNameOfShare:@"BELAZ"];
            [BELAZ setPurchaseSharePrice:24.43];
            [BELAZ setNumberOfShares:89];
            [BELAZ setCurrentSharePrice:108.93];

            Portfolio *portfolio = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, BELAZ, nil];


            NSLog(@"%.2f", [portfolio totalPortfolio]);

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы прочитайте сообщение об ошибке в консоли:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[Portfolio initWithCapacity:]!
```

Суть в том, что, вызывая `-initWithObjects:`, вы на деле вызываете и метод `-initWithCapacity:`, который, как видно из лога, должен быть написан отдельно для каждого дочернего класса `NSArray`.

Вообще, наследование от NSArray — дело не такое уж и простое, потому что это не обычный класс, а так называемый [`Class Cluster`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html): класс-обёртка над кучей других классов.
О правильном наследовани от абстрактных классов можно прочитать в этой [замечательной статье](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html).

---

Что касается решения вашей проблемы: я бы не стал мудрить и определил бы класс `Portfolio` следующим образом:

```
@interface Portfolio : NSObject
{
    NSArray *_stocks;
}

// У нас может быть различное количество аргументов; главное, чтобы
// последним шёл `nil`.
- (id)initWithStocks: (id)first, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
- (CGFloat)totalValue;

@end

/* ------------ CUT HERE --------------- */

@implementation Portfolio

- (id)initWithStocks: (id)first, ...
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if (!first) {
            return self;
        }

        NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray array];

        // Работаем со списком аргументов
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, first);
        StockHolding *stock = first;

        while (stock != nil) {
            [tmp addObject: stock];
            stock = va_arg(args, StockHolding*);
        }
        va_end(args);

        _stocks = [tmp copy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (CGFloat)totalValue
{
    CGFloat sum = 0.0;
    for (StockHolding *stock in _stocks) {
        sum += stock.valueInDollars;
    }

    return sum;
}

@end
```

Ну и в `main.m` прийдётся изменить вызов на

```
    Portfolio *portfolio = [[Portfolio alloc] initWithStocks: DHL, Sony, EPAM, BELAZ, nil];

    NSLog(@"%.2f", [portfolio totalValue]);
```

---

*P.S. разумеется, можно было пойти ещё дальше и упростить всё до ужаса, реализовав протокол [`NSFastEnumeration`](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) для нашего класса, чтобы можно было писать прямо:*

```
    for (StockHolding *stock in self) {
        sum += stock.valueInDollars;
    }
```

и на самом деле это [совсем не сложно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827826/implementing-nsfastenumerator-on-custom-class), но не так интересно `(^^,)`

---

**Ссылки по теме:**

- Паттерн [«Фасад»](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))
- [Переменное число аргументов в функциях Си](http://typedef.ru/2010/03/varying-argument-count-in-c-functions/)
- [NSFastEnumeration Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html)
- [Make Your Own Abstract Factory Class Cluster in Objective-C](http://seanmurph.com/weblog/make-your-own-abstract-factory-class-cluster-in-objective-c/)
- Глава 9 «Use the Class Cluster Pattern to Hide Implementation Detail» в книге [«Effective Objective-C 2.0: 52 Specific Ways to Improve Your iOS and OS X Programs»](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321917014)